# How to resolve the NZEC error on Codechef?

Tags: java, runtime-error

This is the code, which is working fine on my machine. But while submitting it in Codechef there is a problem named NZEC error, from which I am not familiar with and don't know how to debug that. Where I am wrong?

Question: https://www.codechef.com/problems/SNELECT

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    class A
     {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{

    int t,i;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    t=sc.nextInt();
    while(t>0)                                //testcases
    {
        int eaten=0,m=0,s=0;
    String a=new String();
    a=sc.next();
    int n= a.length();
    for( i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(a.charAt(i)=='m')                //counting_m&s
            m++;
        else if(a.charAt(i)=='s')
            s++;
    }
    if(a.charAt(0) == 'm' && a.charAt(1)=='s')
    {
        eaten++;                   //mongoos eaten atmost 1 snake
        a=a.substring(0,1)+'x'+a.substring(2);  //removing eaten snake from string
    }
    if(a.charAt(n-1) == 'm' && a.charAt(n-2)=='s')
    {
        eaten++;
        a=a.substring(0,n-2)+'x'+a.substring(n-1);
    }
    for( i=1;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(a.charAt(i) == 'm' && a.charAt(i-1)=='s')
        {
        eaten++;
        a=a.substring(0,i-1)+'x'+a.substring(i);
        }
        else if(a.charAt(i) == 'm' && a.charAt(i+1)=='s')
        {
        eaten++;
        a=a.substring(0,i+1)+'x'+a.substring(i+2);
        }
    }
    if(s-eaten < m)
        System.out.println("mongooses");    //checking the winner
    else if(s- eaten > m)
        System.out.println("snakes");
    else
        System.out.println("tie");
t--;
        }
   }
      }
```

Comment: NZEC is mainly run time error. Check your logic or else include everything in try catch block

Comment: I tried using try catch block but still it is giving NZEC on codechef compiler. But runs without error on my system everytime. can you tell whats wrong in the code??

Comment: Please try to use real words here, Sahil. No-one really thinks that "please" needs abbreviation! Save that for Facebook if you can, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip sir! new here. Can you tell whats wrong in my code??

Comment: @sahilmehta read this article on quora https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-various-reasons-that-can-cause-NZEC-errors-on-online-coding-platforms

Comment: I still can't understand the problem in my code. Still giving error while submitting on codechef. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NZEC is a runtime error.
It mostly occurs when negative array index is accessed or the program which we have written takes up more space than the allocated memory for our program to run.Try:

```
try{
    // code which you think might throw exception
}catch(java.lang.Throwable t){ 
    // code to catch that exception or simply don't give any code leave it blank
}
```

Throwable class is super class of all error and exception classes in Java.