# RunTime Error (NZEC) even though the code returns the right answer

Tags: java, performance

I am having this task: In Olympics, the countries are ranked by the total number of medals won. You are given six integers G1, S1, B1, and G2, S2, B2, the number of gold, silver and bronze medals won by two different counties respectively. Determine which country is ranked better on the leaderboard. It is guaranteed that there will not be a tie between the two countries.>

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

enter code here

{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        
        int t;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        t=sc.nextInt();
        while(t>0)
        {
            int a1,b1,c1,a2,b2,c2;
            a1= sc.nextInt();
            b1= sc.nextInt();
            c1= sc.nextInt();
            a2= sc.nextInt();
            b2= sc.nextInt();
            c2= sc.nextInt();
            
            if(a1+b1+c1>=a2+b2+c2)
            {
                System.out.println("1");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/a/62072426/139985

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to decrement the value of your test case variable t in the while loop.
So add t-- inside your while loop.